# Trouble with 13 inch MacBook Pro & about buying AppleCare

Tags: macbook-pro, warranty, applecare

This is the 2nd time I have trouble with my 13" MacBook Pro, which I have purchased a little less than 1 year ago, in october 2011.

First time it was 6-7 months ago—the logic board was short circuited—, about which I have posted here. As it was under warranty, I got it repaired.

Now, about a month and half ago, when I was using it, a reddish tint appeared on the screen and after few moments the screen start displaying different colors.

After that, whenever I turned it on, there was no desktop display. Instead it was only showing different colors like red, green, blue, grey etc. **one at a time & in full screen**. I mean, the whole screen shows one color and nothing else is visible. At that time, within 2-3 days I got to fly to south-Korea on a business trip for a month and I thought I will get it repaired after getting back. But now the trip is extended and it looks like I won’t be able to get it repaired in warranty time.

What can be the reason for this defect? Why is it showing different colors on screen?

It’s warranty is expiring on 10th of October.

My question is: can I purchase AppleCare from Korea and use it for my MacBook Pro which I purchased from India?

Also, can AppleCare be registered after the warranty expires? Because Apple says on its web site to buy AppleCare before warranty time is over. It does not say anything about registering it.

Comment: You have to buy AND register it before the warranty expires.

Answer (score 2):

AppleCare is worldwide, and you can purchase it anytime within the first year warranty. It takes effect from the end of your warranty whenever you buy it as long as you register it at some point during that year, so just go ahead and buy it now.

Comment: This was mostly true in 2012 but not so much anymore. Much of AppleCare is regionalized to be harmonious with local consumer protections and also requires purchase within weeks or months of the serialized sale. People waiting till the end of the year and people suing Apple have changed the economics of Apple offering more uniform and generous terms to get AppleCare in 2019.

Comment: Also, OP here seems to be one of the people with a unit known to have problems and then only wanting to pay for AppleCare after it’s no longer new. Not saying they damaged it, but the waiting period makes the cost of the pool higher if everyone doesn’t opt in at the start.